# What is the difference between "She is always obsessed with long hair" and "She is always obsessing about long hair"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, phrase-usage

According to my research

"**She is always obsessed with long hair**" means she is thinking about long hair too much, maybe she wants to have long hair badly.

"**She is always obsessing about long hair**" means she is talking about long hair too much but not sure she wants to have it badly or not.

What is the difference between "**She is always obsessed with long hair**" and "**She is always obsessing about long hair**"?

Comment: What don't you understand about the difference between being obsessed and obsessing?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, I do but the dictionary says there is difference between

Comment: For starters, "obsessed" is an adjective describing her state of mind, while "is...obsessing" is a verb describing her behaviour. That's a pretty big difference, and it seems reflected in your research

Comment: You don't really need _always_ in the first sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is%20obsessed%2Cis%20obsessing&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20obsessed%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20obsessing%3B%2Cc0) shows, the second usage - "*is obsessing*" - is quite recent.

According to [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/obsess) the difference is pretty much as you describe. ****To be obsessed**** is to be preoccupied "to a troubling extent," while **to obsess** is be "constantly talking or worrying about something."

If you click on "More example sentences" you'll see that many examples of the *second* usage seem to be drawn from blogs. They're more informal and chatty and less writerly than those of the *first* usage.